# Extjs Chart numeric y-axis as integer

Tags: extjs, charts, extjs4, axis, axis-labels

I'm trying to display the numeric y-axis as integer... without luck, always shows decimals.

Please if you found a way to do this reply to me. You can find the code here for easy testing: http://jsfiddle.net/adriansky/4uY7H/

```
var store1 = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['name', {name: 'people', type: 'integer' }],
    data:[
        {"name":"jan",  "people":13},
        {"name":"feb",  "people":12},
        {"name":"mar",  "people":12},
        {"name":"apr",  "people":13},
        {"name":"may",  "people":12},
        {"name":"june", "people":13}
    ]
});

var chart = Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: '80%',
    height: '80%',
    store: store1,
    axes: [{
        type: 'Numeric',
        position: 'left',
        fields: ['people'],
    }, {
        type: 'Category',
        position: 'bottom',
        fields: ['name'],
    }],
    series: [{
        type: 'line',
        axis: 'left',
        xField: 'name',
        yField: 'people',
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following on your `Numeric` axes:

```
label: {
    renderer: function (v) {
        return v.toFixed(0); 
    }
}
```

Then, you can also add the minimum and maximum config for that axes. Example:

```
minimum : 0
```

Or on controller:

```
myChart.axes.items[0].maximum = NaN;
myChart.axes.items[0].minimum = 0;
```

Values depend on your data or your display preferences.

Comment: It's almost right, but I if change my dataset to be numbers around 4 and 3 it's going to repeat numbers. http://jsfiddle.net/4uY7H/4/ ...Any thoughts in how to avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

I did this, it took me a while

you have to redefine the whole y-axis, recalculate majorunits etc..

lets assume your chart is called monkeyChart,

once your chart is built, just call monkeyChart.setYAxis(..)

```
monkeyChart.setYAxis(createNumericAxis(min, max, optCfg));



createNumericAxis: function(start, end, optCfg) {
    var cfg = {
        majorUnit: calculateMajorUnit(start, end)
    };
    Ext.apply(cfg, optCfg)
    return new Ext.chart.NumericAxis(cfg);
},

calculateMajorUnit: function(min, max){
    if(min == undefined) min = 0;
    if(max == undefined) max = 20;
    var dif = max - min;
    var interval = dif / 20;
    var intervals = [1,2,5,10,20,50,100,200,500];
    for (var i = 0; i < intervals.length; i++) {
        if(interval <= intervals[i]){
            interval = intervals[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    return interval;
},
```

of course you have to adjust the numbers as you like, eg the intervals you want to see (I did this way so I can have a different density depending on the values)

also if you don't know min and max beforhead you can just pass undefined for both, and an empty object as optCfg

give it a try, I wrote it long time ago I might have missed something now

Answer (score 0):

my previous answer was for ext js 3.4

in your case if you use both

```
majorTickSteps: 1,
minimum: 0,
```

seems working

http://jsfiddle.net/alezx/vu5pL/

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/4uY7H/2/

```
axes: [{
    type: 'Numeric',
    position: 'left',
    fields: ['people'],
    decimals: 0,
    majorTickSteps: 1,
}, {
    type: 'Category',
    position: 'bottom',
    fields: ['name'],
}],
```

check the doc for Ext.chart.axis.Numeric and Ext.chart.axis.Axis

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.chart.axis.Axis

Comment: I tried that one, but if you notice it's repeating integer numbers (which is undesirable)... I have been playing with majorTickSteps, minumumTickSteps, minimum and maximum but no luck...